# possible unsafe site in google analtycs

Tags: google-analytics

I found an url with **/__*possible*_unsafe_*site*_** at the end in google analytics stats.

I can't understand why??

The landing page is safe.

Do you know what it means?

Comment: could you paste the code here?

Comment: This seems to be like hacked site. You may check with VirusTotal's URL scanner just to be sure. [https://www.virustotal.com/en/](https://www.virustotal.com/en/)

Comment: I'm enough sure there aren't virus, I scanned the site finding nothing and Web master tool says no malware.